# jQuery: modify href attribute for first level list only

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm a noob in jQuery and have stuck at this. I have the following HTML code output from a PHP page:

```
<ul class="cats">
  <li><span><a href="cant_post_link_yet1">Lifestyle</a></span></li>
  <li><span><a href="cant_post_link_yet2">Entertainment</a></span></li>
  <li class="has_child">
    <span><a href="cant_post_link_yet3">Technology</a></span>
    <ul class="subcats">
      <li><span><a href="cant_post_link_yet4">Gadgets</a></span></li>
      <li><span><a href="cant_post_link_yet5">Hardware</a></span></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><span><a href="cant_post_link_yetsports">Sports</a></span></li>
  <li class="has_child">
    <span><a href="cant_post_link_yet6">Design</a></span>
    <ul class="subcats">
      <li class="has_child">
        <span><a href="cant_post_link_yet7">Web Design</a></span>
        <ul class="subcat">
          <li><span><a href="cant_post_link_yet8">Adobe Photoshop</a></span></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><span><a href="cant_post_link_yet9">Graphics and Print</a></span></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

What's the correct jQuery code so that I can modify the **href** attribute for the **first-level list** only? Basically, I want to change the **href** of **Technology** and **Design** to be **"#"** but will not change the href of **Web Design** which is already on second-level list.

More Info:
In the code above, if list has subcategories, then it has the class **has_child**, whether it's on first-level or not. So I want only the **first-level list** which has class **has_child** to be modified the **href to "#"** I can't alter output anymore because it's in the PHP code.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways of doing it. The most straightforward is to trace the child elements directly:

```
$("ul.cats > li > span > a").attr("href", "....");
```

Of course that has issues if the anchors aren't contained in spans. You can instead take an exclusionary approach:

```
$("ul.cats > li > :not(ul) a").attr("href", "...");
```

This will be slower but might be closer to the intended semantics. It does suffer from a similar issue to the first in that the child lists might not be directly below the list element.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, it's what I am looking for - the first code.

I have almost similar approach earlier: $("ul.cats > li span  a").attr("href", "...."); and it did not work. Can you point me out what's the wrong with it?

Comment: See my answer and check whether it works. Also the HTML you have posted is not well formed.

Comment: @rahul
Yes this one and yours is working perfectly but I'm using your answer since it's specific to .has_child. The HTMl I posted has missing </ul> since it's not the complete output.

Comment: @bloggerious yours doesn't work because `>` is a child selector and without that it's a descendant selector so `ul.cat > li span a` will find the direct children of `ul.cats` but then find all `span a` descendants, which includes the links in the child lists. That's why mine has `>` all the way down.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. At least I learn a little day by day :)

Answer (score 1):

```
$("ul.cats > li.has_child > span > a").attr("href","#");
```

`ul.cats > li.has_child` selects all first level li elements with class name `has_child` inside the ul with class name `cats`. `> span > a` then selects all `a` elements which are first level elements inside `span` which is direct child of the previous selector.